# Uploading image from ImageVIew to remote server

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to upload an image from a ImageView to a remote server.

This is my code:

```
func subir_imagen(){

        let image = self.foto.image
        let imgData = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!

         let parameters = ["name": "jogua"] //Optional for extra parameter

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "fileset",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                for (key, value) in parameters {
                        multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                    } //Optional for extra parameters
            },
        to:"https://.../subir_foto_dispositivo.php")
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response)
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }

    }
```

This is the file subir_foto_dispositivo.php:

```
 // Save the image file
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

 // Send some dummy result back to the iOS app
 $result = array();
 $result["user"] = $user;
 $result["message"] = "Success!";
 $result["files"] = $_FILES;
 $result["post"] = $_POST;
 echo json_encode($result);
```

And this is the output in debugger when uploading an image:

```
Upload Progress: 0.21640112366409928
Upload Progress: 0.4362101390394442
Upload Progress: 0.6628349378372804
Upload Progress: 0.8485650361001688
Upload Progress: 1.0
SUCCESS: {
    files =     {
        fileset =         {
            error = 0;
            name = "file.jpg";
            size = 9615058;
            "tmp_name" = "/tmp/phpH6Au4W";
            type = "image/jpg";
        };
    };
    message = "Success!";
    post =     {
        name = jogua;
    };
    user = "<null>";
}
```

I am not getting any warning or error, but the image is not uploaded to the server, at least I can't find it in the folder.

I guess I am missing something.

Comment: Apart from the force unwrapping the code seems fine. Have you tried to upload image using postman?

Comment: @Frankenstein, not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func requestPostURLForUploadImage(success:@escaping (Dictionary<String,Any>) -> Void, failure:@escaping (Error) -> Void){
    var image = self.foto.image
    var strUrl = "http://103.51.0.xxx/papp_name/index.php/api/"  // your server url here where image needs to upload

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        let imgData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "image_one",fileName:"uploadimageName", mimeType: "image/jpg")

    }, to: strUrl)
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _ ,_ ):
            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                let resJson = response.result.value
                if resJson != nil{
                    let res = resJson as! Dictionary<String, String>
                    if res.count > 0 {
                        success(resJson as! Dictionary<String, String>)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    print("Response not found")
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but  I don't see in your code where to get the image from the ImageView.

Comment: I have updated an answer please check it works for you or not.

Comment: I would need to know where do i get in my case ImageParameter, I am not able to follow your code in my case

Comment: same result, upload progress is showing, success result, but file not uploaded

Comment: I think may be problem with php code and I don't have that much idea about php ☹️ 
 may be file is uploaded properly through iOS code but it may not get saved correctly in the folder 
or try once uploaded then move the file in some other location and then try to retrieve the same file through iOS code.

this link may help
[https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp]